# G code simulation in NC Viewer for Manufacturing Engineering

Tags: simulation

I am trying to simulate the following code in NC Viewer (https://ncviewer.com/).

```
O001 
N10 G20 G90
N20 M06 T1 
N30 M03 S500
N40 M08
N50 G01 X0.25 Y0.25 Z0.25
N60 G00 Z-0.25 F2
N70 G01 X0.4 Y1.75
N80 G01 X0.8 Y0.25
N90 G00 X0.3 Y0.8 Z0.25
N100 G00 Z-.25
N110 G01 X0.65 Y0.8
```

But when I simulate (by pressing the icon highlighted in the image below) it the tool moves rapidly. Is there any way to slow it down?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double arrows on the far left and far right increase or decrease the speed at which it steps through the code. If you click them it enough times it will actually start to go in reverse.

It seems a bit buggy though and doesn't always have the same behaviour. Might need to press stop then play or just refresh the page.